# Finite cyclic $\Bbb Z$-module and exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, cyclic-groups, exact-sequence

> Suppose $M$ is $\Bbb Z$-module, cyclic, finite.
>   How to prove
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     0 @>>> \Bbb Z @>>> \Bbb Z @>>> M @>>>0\\
>     \end{CD}
>   is short exact sequence?

in fact we must prove : $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>f>> \Bbb Z @>g>> \Bbb Z @>h>> M @>k>>0\\
    \end{CD}
$f,g,h,k$ exist s.t. $Im f=Kerg, Img=Kerh,Imh=Kerk$

in other way: $g,h$ exist s.t $g$ is one-one function,$h$ is onto function, $Img=Kerh$

if $g=i$ ,$g$ is one-one function, $h=?$,$M=a \Bbb Z$, $h$ is onto but $Img\not =Kerh$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to prove that

> if $M$ is a finite cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then there exists a short exact sequence
>   $$
> 0\to \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to M\to 0
> $$

Let $x$ be a generator of $M$ and consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to M$ defined by $f(n)=nx$. This is a surjective homomorphism and its kernel is of the form $\ker f=k\mathbb{Z}$, with $k>0$.

> Surjectivity follows by definition of cyclic module and the fact that $x$ is a generator. The homomorphism theorem says that $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\cong M$, so $k=|M|$. We, of course, use the fact that a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $r\mathbb{Z}$, for a unique $r\in\mathbb{N}$, and that, for $r>0$, $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ has $r$ elements.

Consider now the map $\mu_k\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\mu_k(n)=nk$.

> It is obviously a homomorphism; moreover it is injective, because $k>0$ and so, from $\mu_k(n)=0$ we deduce $n=0$.

Is the sequence
$$
0\to \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\mu_k}\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f} M\to 0
$$
exact?

> Yes; $\mu_k$ is injective and $f$ is surjective. Moreover, the image of $\mu_k$ is clearly $k\mathbb{Z}$ which is equal to $\ker f$.

Comment: $\ker f\not = k \Bbb Z$, since $\ker f =\{n\in \Bbb Z | nx=0_M=n'x \}=\{n\in \Bbb Z |(n-n')x=0\}, n'=0$ since $\Bbb Z$ is integer domain, $x\not = 0$

Comment: @Alex You're wrong: $\ker f=k\mathbb{Z}$, where $k=|M|$. Any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $r\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $r$ and $\ker f$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ok. that's right, $\ker f =\{0\} = k \Bbb Z , k=0$,since $nx=0 \rightarrow n=0 , (x\not =0)$.

Comment: @Alex The kernel of $f$ cannot be $\{0\}$, because $M$ is finite by hypothesis. On the other hand the kernel of $\mu_k$ is $\{0\}$, because $kn=0$ implies $n=0$, since $k>0$.

Comment: @Alex I added spoilers. However, before looking at them you should convince yourself that $nx=0$ ***doesn't*** imply $n=0$, because $x\in M$ which is ***very*** different from an integral domain: it is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ and it is finite. Hence *for all $x\in M$ there exists $n>0$ with $nx=0$*.